# Tor service doens't work correctly from my user folder (service starts, but network unavailable)

Tags: error, troubleshooting

I unpacked *Tor Expert Bundle* to `C:\` and run `tor --service install -options -f <path_to_my_torrc>`, the service succesfully installs and runs. Tor Network works fine.

But when I tried to install *Tor Expert Bundle* from my user directory (win8, something like `C:\User\<Cyrillic user name>\Desktop\Tor`), the service installs but can't start with *error "access denied"*. I added rules:

```
icacls %cd% /grant "LOCAL SERVICE":(OI)(CI)RX
icacls %cd%\Data /grant "LOCAL SERVICE":(OI)(CI)M
```

Then the service installs and starts correctly, but tor network doesn't work.

My `torrc` file:

```
#DataDirectory C:\Users\Андрей\Desktop\Tor Expert Bundle\Data
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Андрей\Desktop\Tor Expert Bundle\Data\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Андрей\Desktop\Tor Expert Bundle\Data\geoip6

ExcludeExitNodes {ru}, {ua}, {by}, {kz}
ExitNodes {pl}
```

I tried to add *quotes* to file paths, but i got error 1064.
I tried to add `DataDirectory` parameter, but i also got error 1064.

When I run *Tor Browser Bundle* from the same directory, tor succesfully starts. How to place tor expert bundle in my user directory (with cyrillic symbols in the file path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured by cyrillic symbols. Quick solution is using in torrc for TEB paths, generated by TBB for their torrc. True way: encode your non-latin symbols to escaped octal CP-1251 numbers, escaping all *other* slashes in path and path quotation. For example:
`DataDirectory C:\Users\Андрей\Desktop\Tor Expert Bundle\Data` ->
`DataDirectory "C:\\Users\\\300\355\344\360\345\351\\Desktop\\Tor Expert Bundle\\Data"`
This variant works, all other tested (without quotes, double escaping, etc) don't.